# XmlWriter create SEPA XML

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to create a SEPA XML with `XmlWriter`. The created XML has to look like this example:

http://www.ebics.de/fileadmin/unsecured/anlage3/anlage3_pain008/pain_ex/pain.008.003.02.xml

This is my code so far:

```
        public void generateSepaXml()
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("C:\\Users\\Sybren\\Documents\\test.xml",settings))
        {
            String messageId = "Message ID";

            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("Document"); //Document start
            writer.WriteAttributeString("xsi",@"schemaLocation=""urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.003.02 pain.008.003.02.xsd");
            writer.WriteStartElement("CstmrDrctDbtInitn"); // CstmrDrctDbtInitn tag start
            writer.WriteStartElement("GrpHdr"); //GrpHeader tag start
            writer.WriteStartElement("MsgId",messageId); //Message tag start
            writer.WriteEndElement(); //Message tag end
            writer.WriteEndElement(); //GrpHdr end
            writer.WriteEndElement(); //CstmrDrctDbtInitn tag end
            writer.WriteEndElement(); //Document end
            writer.WriteEndDocument();


        }
    }
```

The result of my code looks like this:

[image]

How can set the text in the Document tag the same to the Document tag in my example?
And for the message tag `xmlns` is added when I open the xml in IE. The `xmlns` tag isn't visible in the result image above (in Firefox). How to remove this tag? And how can I set the text in the `MsgId` the same to the `MsgId` in the linked example xml? Maybe XMLWriter isn't the best option in my case? If so what is another better option?
Ofcourse this is only a small part of the XML but if know how it works , I think I can do the rest myself.

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time - you'll have to select one answer as correct, and if different of your sub-questions receive the best answers in different answers, that introduces chaos and confusion to future visitors. Also, try to simplify your question and example to the most abstract level you require; I suspect none of these questions is specific to SEPA XML, instead, they seem to deal with generic Xml issues.

Comment: With that said, yes, all of those are possible with `XmlWriter`, it's a (not the only one) good choice.

Comment: Okay nice to hear that it's possible with `XmLWriter`. And the main question is how can make my generated xml part look exactly the same as the part in the provided link.

Comment: Just because it´s possible using `XmlWriter` does not mean it´s a suitable solution...

Answer (score 0):

Just a well-meant advise (since I have some experience in the area of financial data-exchange, especially with `SEPA`)... I would not try to implement that shit using such a low-level `XML` API; there´re better ways to create complex `XML` documents than assembling them piece-by-piece with `XmlWriter`.

Since `SEPA` documents can become quite big, achieving it the way you´re trying will probably result in unmaintainable and error-prone spaghetti code. Instead, I would recommend to investigate into a model-driven approach (one for each `SEPA` use-case to implement) and then use a generator (consider using an intermediate `XML` format that can be transformed using `XSLT`) or a text-processor to produce the final output...

Comment: I don't think `XSLT` is a good solution, I don't have any knowledge about XSL Stylesheet? What's a better option `XmlDocument`, `XmlTextWriter` or something else?

Comment: You already got the answer... `XmlDocument` and `XmlTextWriter` belong to the same API. Since your code is probably dealing with someone else money, you should better do your homework (-: `XSLT` is worth to think about, even if it looks complicated at the first glance... Believe me, it´s way simpler to understand than the confusing and somewhat cluttered `SEPA` spec...

Comment: I wanna the use `XmlWriter` anyway. Can you help with the question in my OP?

Comment: I answered the conceptional questions; two actually... For the API related questions you may consult the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have read the docs but how remove `xmlns` tag from the `MsgId` tag?